# How to add arrow on the right of drop down list button using CSS

Tags: html, css, polymer

I'm developing drop down list in polymer. Currently I have problem with CSS.

Here you can find example:

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9ayyzudh/5/)

```
<div style="width:200px" class="button initial gray">
<div style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;">
<div class="button-value truncated" style="width:inherit;">
Select value very long label with dots at the end
</div>
<div class="arrow">&#x25BC;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to create the following drop down list, but I have problem with arrow visible on the right of button.

Question is, how to achieve this:

[gif example](https://preview.ibb.co/m2imYS/example.gif)

I will be very grateful for your help !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

then you will see the three dots after your list item, but also you need to add `width` for your `span`

```
width: 100px
```

Code example

```
<div style="width:200px" class="button initial gray">
  <div style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;">
    <div class="button-value truncated" style="width:158px; display: inline-block">
      Select value very long label with dots at the end
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-top: 12px;vertical-align: top;"class="arrow">&#x25BC;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question with links to examples, I had some problems before. Please check gif example, I have tried text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden, but after it arrow is positioned in wrong place

Comment: I added an image for your example, check my answer

Comment: thank you very much ! this is exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

```css
     div.button.orange {
        border: 1px solid #FF6200;
        background: inherit;
        background-color: #FF6200;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-family: 'ING Me';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 36px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px lightgray;
      }

      div.button.gray {
        border: 1px solid #767676;
        background: inherit;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-family: 'ING Me';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #FF6200;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 36px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px lightgray;
        position:relative;
        
      }

      div.button.gray.initial {
        color: #767676;
      }

      div.button.active {
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
        border: 1px solid #FF6200;
      }

      div.button-value {
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 36px;
        width: inherit;
      }

      ul.options>li {
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
        line-height: 36px;
      }

      .truncated {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      ul.options {
        color: black;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        margin: -1px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid #FF6200;
        border-top: none;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px lightgray;
      }

      ul.options>ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      ul.options>li:hover {
        color: white;
        background-color: #FF6200;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      
      .arrow{
        position:absolute;
        right:4px;
        top:0;
        line-height:36px;
        }
```

```html
<div style="width:200px" class="button initial gray">
  <div style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:18px;">
    <div class="button-value truncated" style="width:inherit;">
      Select value very long label with dots at the end&#x25BC;
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">&#x25BC;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```